# How to retrieve data from a select tag that is nested inside a tr tag with Selenium?

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I hope everybody is doing good!

I have a task that I do not know pretty well how to solve it. So let me start with the beginning:

1. I want to scrap from a web page (a map) details about the streets and associated numbers. For this job, I chose Selenium. I watched some tutorials and different answers but unsuccessfully.

The first part, was to retrieve the streets. This part I managed to accomplish. The page looks like this:

[image]

So there is a table with a bunch `<tr>` tags from which I managed to retrieve the needed data. However, the things got a bit more complicated once I needed to find a way to retrieve the Numbers.
Numbers of the streets are located in a `<select>` tag which APPEARS ONLY when I click on the given tag. So, from the previous image, the structure becomes like this:

[image]

But again, only **IF** I click on the `<tr>` tag. If I click another `<tr>` tag, the `<select>` tag from the previous `<tr>` disappears, and pops to the one selected with corresponding `<option>` tags.

Now, my question is: How can I iterate through entire table, click on each `<tr>` and **IF** a `<select>` tag pops up, to retrieve the numbers associated to each Street?

I would like to store the result in a dictionary where the key is the name of the street, and as values, the numbers associated.

So far, this is the code I wrote, which of course, fails to solve my problem.

**UPDATE 3:**

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(path_ex))

driver.get("https://cluj-city.map2web.eu/")

wait = WebDriverWait(driver,30)

# panel = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR,"h4#titleStreets")
panel = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"h4#titleStreets")))
panel.click()

streets = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH,"//table[@id='streets']/tbody/tr/td")

# for i in range(len(streets)):
for i in range(10): # Tried for 10 elements.
    streets = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//table[@id='streets']/tbody/tr")
    print(streets[i].find_element(By.XPATH,"./td").text)
    streets[i].find_element(By.XPATH,"./td").click()
    time.sleep(2)
    try:
        numbers = streets[i].find_elements(By.XPATH,"./td/select/option")
        num_list = []
        for i in range(len(numbers)):
            num_list.append(numbers[i].get_attribute("value"))
        print(num_list)
    except:
        print("No numbers")
```

**Error I get**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/tudor/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/beat.py", line 18, in <module>
    panel = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"h4#titleStreets")))
  File "/home/tudor/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/support/wait.py", line 89, in until
    raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message:
```

Comment: Just use a try except for the select. You can just check if it exists or not. Also .// to xpath from an element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like below once and confirm.

```
driver.get("https://cluj-city.map2web.eu/")

wait = WebDriverWait(driver,30)

# panel = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR,"h4#titleStreets")
panel = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"h4#titleStreets")))
panel.click()

streets = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH,"//table[@id='streets']/tbody/tr/td")

# for i in range(len(streets)):
for i in range(10): # Tried for 10 elements.
    streets = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//table[@id='streets']/tbody/tr")
    print(streets[i].find_element(By.XPATH,"./td").text)
    streets[i].find_element(By.XPATH,"./td").click()
    time.sleep(2)
    try:
        numbers = streets[i].find_elements(By.XPATH,"./td/select/option")
        num_list = []
        for i in range(len(numbers)):
            num_list.append(numbers[i].get_attribute("value"))
        print(num_list)
    except:
        print("No numbers")
```

**Output**

```
Aleea Albăstrelelor
[]
Aleea Alexandru Lapedatu
['0', '672723', '673946', '672724', '686707', '685369', '674092', '685370', '674093', '685371', '685379', '686708', '674094', '686710', '686711']
Aleea Anemonelor
['0', '674371']
Aleea Azaleelor
['0', '686876', '686847', '667291', '669662', '686877', '686878']
Aleea Azuga
['0', '675419', '661994', '676263', '662870', '666294', '665524', '675422', '662090']
Aleea Azur
[]
Aleea Băişoara
['0', '675416', '685313', '662861', '673532', '665446', '675426', '678804', '663696', '661674', '661988', '672374', '675431']
Aleea Băiţa
['0', '666522', '678447', '661990', '662881', '661992', '661993', '665375', '662880', '661987', '661995', '676267']
Aleea Bâlea
['0', '676268', '676266', '662865', '662866', '663658', '665715', '686000', '686014', '686012', '686013', '686015', '673391', '686019', '686020', '686007', '686801', '686010', '662878']
Aleea Bârsei
['0', '663687', '675417', '662871', '676265', '663692']
```

Comment: Hello @pmadhu! First, I'd like to thank you for your reply! I tried your code, but for some reason it raises this error: `selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotInteractableException: Message: element not interactable`, and this comes from `elements[i].click()`.  Thank you very much  !!!!! 
https://cluj-city.map2web.eu/, this is also the link, maybe it'll help you.

Comment: @geekt - How to view `<select>` tags. What are the steps to be taken.

Comment: Lookin with inspect element, I cannot say wether is JavaScript which actually unhide the content when clicking on the `<tr>` tag. As there is no `<a>` tag, nor button, I believe that this is some sort of toggle down script that displays the data. 
To view the `<select>` tags, simply click on `Strazi - (Streets)`, a drop down will appear, and then click on a street, and a `<select>` tag will appear.

Comment: @geekt - Have updated the code. Have shared the Output too. Need first click on the panel-> dropdown and then try to click on those street options.

Comment: This is exactly what I neeed man @pmadhu!!!! But on my computer, for some reason, I don't understand why it still throws an error. I updated my code with yours, and I will share the error and entire traceback.

Comment: I also operate on Linux, with the version of Chrome installed: `chrome=98.0.4758.102`

Comment: @geekt - Panel element is the drop down option.   Add some waits and try.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/242624/discussion-between-geekt-and-pmadhu).

Comment: @geekt - Have updated code again. Have added Explicit wait block.

Comment: I wrote you something in discussion room. I think it is a problem with my system configuration on my end. I also updated the code with yours, and I still have an error. @pmadhu

Comment: @geekt - I saw the message in chat room. Have replied too. Any way through API using `request` module we can extract only the street names. Let me know if you want to know more about that.